# Secure Textfield value in UIAutomation script

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, ios-ui-automation

I have a login screen with username field and password field. In the UIAutomation script i have accessed the password field as

```
var passwordField = window.secureTextFields()["password"];
```

But when i accessed the value of passwordField after entering the value via uiautomation script by

```
var password = passwordField.value();
```

But i am getting the value for password as  black dots (••••) ie as default masking character of iPhone. How can i get the real value of the password?

Comment: This is by design to protect the value of the field. It's only accessible from Objective C. What are you trying to grab the password for? Maybe there's some other way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Have you found out the answer for this question ?